# Erro estrutura do projeto Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Meu projeto começou a apresentar o erro abaixo quando executo qualquer comando `php artisan ...`:

> ```
>  $ php artisan --version 
>    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>    ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:767
>    Stack trace:
>    #0 Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(767): ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
>    #1 Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(646): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
>    #2 Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(601): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Arr ay)
>    #3 Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(735): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Arr ay)
>    #4 Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1210): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config')
>    #5 Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework in Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 767
>
>   Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:767
>    Stack trace:
>    #0 Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(767): ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
>    #1 Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(646): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
>    #2 Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(601): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Arr ay)
>    #3 Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(735): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Arr ay)
>    #4 Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1210): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config')
>    #5 Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework in Y:\public\book\projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 767
> ```

Consigo executar nenhum comando, porém o que está pronto funciona, alguém pode dá uma força?

Comment: tenta rodar esse comando composer dump-autoload

Comment: Voltou com os mesmos erros e a mensagem abaixo:
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

Comment: pior é que todos os projetos no servidor apresenta este erro, então é algo relacionado ao composer mesmo creio eu

Comment: procura no diretorio a pasta vendor, veja se ela existe! e testa esse comando php artisan clear-compiled, se não corrigir da uma conferida no seu .env e veja se está tudo correto e sem caracteres especiais!

Comment: se não der certo testa isso também composer update && composer dump-autoload e da um confere nesse link https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-erro-ao-executar-php-artisan-serve-37460   Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver, caso alguém tenha este tipo de problema, eu sempre usei o php 7.2, dai veio outro programador e instalou o php 7.0 para rodar outro projeto, quando voltei o php 7.2 na minha máquina voltou tudo ao normal.

Comment: Sim o Laravel 5.7 tem que ter o `PHP >= 7.1.3` eu ia falar isso pra tu agora.